# run script when length change jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a plugin which appends a button to the label (id="dowloadify") below.

I want to run a ajax post request after the button appends. My jquery code is below. It doesn't work.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){    
  if($("#downloadify").children().length==1){  
      $.post( 
            "update.php",
             { dates:'<?php echo $dates; ?>',
              caseid:'<?php echo $caseid; ?>'
              },
             function(data) {
            //alert(data);
               $('#dates').val(data);
              });
        }
 });
</script>
```

Comment: Your `if` statement is executed once on DOM ready. You should listen to an event. The plugin should trigger events.

Comment: Maybe your code is being run before the plugin's code? Make sure it runs after the button is appended.

Comment: Why not run the code when you do the append?

Comment: how i get event button   appended

Comment: What is name of the plugin? How do you initialize it?

Comment: You should do the ajax call inside a callback of the function adding the button

Comment: docxtemplater  it generate button to download docs  javascript-ninja.fr/docxgenjs/examples/demo.html#naming

Answer (score -1):

Just do it after you append the child to `#downloadify`

```
$("#downloadify").append(button);
      $.post( 
             "update.php",
             { dates:'<?php echo $dates; ?>',
               caseid:'<?php echo $caseid; ?>'

              },
             function(data) {
                //alert(data);
              $('#dates').val(data);
             });
```

or change your `if` function to `while` and make sure it is **run only once** (using `boolean` value)